# Is it better to force index usage for an ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, range, filesort

I'm currently trying to optimize a query generated by Doctrine 2 on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `publication` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `global_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_AF3C6779B12CE9DB` (`global_order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The query is

```
SELECT *
FROM publication
WHERE type IN ('article', 'event', 'work')
ORDER BY global_order DESC
```

`type` is a discriminator column added by Doctrine. Although the `WHERE` clause is useless as `type` is always one of the `IN` values, I cannot remove it.

`EXPLAIN` shows me

```
+------+---------------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| type | possible_keys | key  | rows |            Extra            |
+------+---------------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| ALL  | NULL          | NULL |  562 | Using where; Using filesort |
+------+---------------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

(`rows` is different each time I execute the query)

After some reading I found I can force an index usage like this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `publication` DROP INDEX  `UNIQ_AF3C6779B12CE9DB` ,
ADD UNIQUE  `UNIQ_AF3C6779B12CE9DB` (  `global_order` ,  `type` )
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM publication
    FORCE INDEX(UNIQ_AF3C6779B12CE9DB) 
WHERE global_order > 0
    AND type IN ('article', 'event', 'work')
ORDER BY global_order DESC
```

The `WHERE` clause is always useless, but this time `EXPLAIN` shows me

```
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
| type  |     possible_keys     |          key          | rows |    Extra    |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
| range | UNIQ_AF3C6779B12CE9DB | UNIQ_AF3C6779B12CE9DB |  499 | Using where |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------+-------------+
```

It seems to me it's better, but it seems it's not common to have to force an index too so I wonder if it's really efficient for such a simple query.

Does anyone know what is the better way to perform this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your query really is:

```
SELECT *
FROM publication
WHERE type IN ('article', 'event', 'work')
ORDER BY global_order DESC
```

... and all entries (or nearly all) will match the IN clause, you're actually better off with no index at all. If you toss in a limit clause, then the index you'll want is actually on `global_order`, without the `type` field. The reason for this is, it actually costs something to read an index.

If you're going for the entire table, sequentially reading the table and sorting its rows in memory will be your cheapest plan. If you only need a few rows and most will match the where clause, going for the smallest index will do the trick.

To understand why, picture the disk IO involved.

Suppose you want the whole table without an index. To do this, you read data_page1, data_page2, data_page3, etc., visiting the various disk pages involved in order, until you reach the end of the table. You then then sort and return.

If you want the top 5 rows without an index, you'd sequentially read the entire table as before, while heap-sorting the top 5 rows. Admittedly, that's a lot of reading and sorting for a handful of rows.

Suppose, now, that you want the whole table with an index. To do this, you read index_page1, index_page2, etc., sequentially. This then leads you to visit, say, data_page3, then data_page1, then data_page3 again, then data_page2, etc., in a completely random order (that by which the sorted rows appear in the data). The IO involved makes it cheaper to just read the whole mess sequentially and sort the grab bag in memory.

If you merely want the top 5 rows of an indexed table, in contrast, using the index becomes the correct strategy. In the worst case scenario you load 5 data pages in memory and move on.

A good SQL query planner, btw, will make its decision on whether to use an index or not based on how fragmented your data is. If fetching rows in order means zooming back and forth across the table, a good planner may decide that it's not worth using the index. In contrast, if the table is clustered using that same index, the rows are guaranteed to be in order, increasing the likelihood that it'll get used.

But then, if you join the same query with another table and that other table has an extremely selective where clause that can use a small index, the planner might decide it's actually better to, e.g. fetch all IDs of rows that are tagged as `foo`, hash join them with publications, and heap sort them in memory.

Comment: Excellent, detailed answer.  +1

Comment: Woops, I thought the bounty was given when the answer is chosen, sorry ^^'

Answer (score 1):

MySQL tries to determine the best way to run a given query, and decides whether or not to use indexes based on what it thinks is the best.

It isn't always correct.  Sometimes manually forcing a query to use an index is faster, sometimes its not.

If you run some testing with sample data in your specific situation, you should be able to see which method performs faster, and stick with that one.

Make sure you take into account query caching to get an accurate performance benchmark.

Comment: You can use the `SQL_NO_CACHE` modifier to `SELECT` to ensure that the resultset is not retrieved from the cache.

Comment: I've not be able to see any significative difference. Maybe 5000 rows is not enough but anyway I'm pretty sure I'm not going to have that much! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the use of an index is rarely the best answer.  In general it is better to create and/or optimize the indices (indexes) so that MySQL chooses to use them.  (It is even better to optimize the queries, but I understand you cannot do that here.)

When you are using something like Doctrine where you cannot optimize the queries and the indices don't help, your best bet is to focus on query caching. :-)